# How to find invisible character in Snowflake

Tags: sql, database, unicode, ascii, snowflake-schema

I am working on pulling data from a dataset where two columns, old_value and new_value should ***NOT*** be equal. But I am getting false rows being fetched.

For Example:

| old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC |

This row should not be fetched but it was there. And upon figuring out why, it showed below:

| old_value | new_value | len(old_value) | len(new_value) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC | 4 | 3 |

I am not sure why it showed "4" for old_value. I did try replacing white space with blank, new line character, regexp_replace, but none worked.

Please suggest how to **find and remove** this invisible character. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expresiions to remove non ascii charters

```
select regexp_replace(old_value, '[^[:ascii:]]', '')
```

the pattern you must adapt to your data